# Retrieving posts from a wordpress blog without authentication

Tags: wordpress

I want to retrieve posts within a period of time from a wordpress blog. Wordpress provides some XML-RPC APIs to do this. However, they all need username and password of the blog. So I'm wondering if there are some other APIs that don't need authentication for retrieving posts? Such as for blogger, I can use a API key to get the posts without authentication. Of course, I can program some for loops to parse the webpages one by one to get the contents, but it's time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins to retrieve posts from other sites and blogs. You can choose any plugin according to your requirement.

[WP RSS Aggregator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator) can be helpful to you.